# How can I change the color of the variable in JS dom?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the color of my text that I displayed on the html by JS on hover
here is the HTML :

```
<div class="text_user_info" id="tui"  onmouseover="hoverText()" onmouseout="noHoverText()" ></div>
```

Here is the JS :

```
 var userName = "Hamdy"
  var userNamef = userName.bold()
  const welcome = "Hello,  "

  document.getElementById("tui").innerHTML = welcome + userNamef;
```

Comment: innerHTML is a HTML compiler. Have you tried `document.getElementById("tui").innerHTML = welcome + "<div class="text_user_info" id="tui"  onmouseover="hoverText()" onmouseout="noHoverText()" >" + userNamef + "</div>"` ?

Comment: You should be using the CSS `:hover` selector for this.

Comment: Your JS code doesn't have any color-related logic. It's just insert greeting text into your HTML. So what do you want? Execute that JS code block when you're hovering the HTML ? or do you want to modify that code so it can change the text color on hover?

Comment: i want userName variable only change the color how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create your functions hoverText and noHoverText and set the style.color as needed

```js
var userName = "Hamdy"
  var userNamef = userName.bold()
  const welcome = "Hello,  "

  document.getElementById("tui").innerHTML = welcome + '<span id="s">'+userNamef + '</span>';
  
  function hoverText(){
    let div = document.getElementById('s')
    div.style.color='blue'
    }
    
    function noHoverText(){
    let div = document.getElementById('s')
    div.style.color='black'
    }
```

```html
<div class="text_user_info" id="tui"  onmouseover="hoverText()" onmouseout="noHoverText()" ></div>
```

Comment: i want userName variable only change the color how can i do it ? and thank you for the help

Comment: snippet updated.  just add a span and target that instead of the entire div